# Load assembly from a path without copying it to bin folder

Tags: c#

I have a simple c# application and I would like to reference an assembly from `C:\..\..myassembly.dll` without copying the thing to bin folder.

I there a way to change how is assembly being referenced/loaded?

Edit: the assembly is not in gac

Comment: you could separately load the assembly using `Assembly` classes `LoadFrom` overload(s).

Comment: Click the reference in the solution and set the `Copy Local` setting to false

Comment: If I set copy local to false my app wont start :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it is possible during runtime by using `<codeBase>` tag in your configuration:

```
<configuration>
<runtime>
   <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
         <assemblyIdentity name="MyAssembly2"  culture="neutral" publicKeyToken="307041694a995978"/>
         <codeBase version="1.0.1524.23149" href="FILE://C:/Myassemblies/MyAssembly2.dll"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
   </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
</configuration>
```

You can refer to the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/efs781xb(v=vs.110).aspx) to get more specific info. The downside of this solution is that you have to manually specify assembly version.

Comment: Could you please provide me with an example

Comment: @devhedgehog Actually I have provided you an example. I can elaborate on it but please specify what is unclear for you.

Comment: I did the same as you showed above except I have multiple dependentAssembly entries. Exactly 4 of them. Two are working but those with publicKeyToken=null are not. Any ideas?

Comment: @devhedgehog Could you elaborate on "are not"?

Comment: i am in wpf, its a crazy story.. but this helped me alot out thanks

Answer (score 0):

Multiple solutions to your problem.

To avoid copying library to output folder set `Copy Local` to false by selecting .dll property.

**Option 1:**

Include below section in your configuration file and let allow runtime to load from location you specified.

```
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="MyAssembly" publicKeyToken="2d65620afb84f19d" />
        <codeBase version="1.0.0.0" href="C:\..\..myassembly.dll" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
```

**Option 2:**

Well known option, use reflection to load your assembly.

```
Assembly.Load(@"C:\..\..myassembly.dll")
```

Hope this helps !